# Scrolling divs not scrolling to bottom of content

Tags: html, css

I have 2 scrolling divs (outlined in red) that will not scroll to the their respective bottoms. I can't seem to seem to figure out what to tweak to fix it.

The thick outlined box is a simulated browser window.

http://jsfiddle.net/jsk55rfb/4/

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="detail-container">
            <div class="top-info"></div>
            <div class="items-container">
                <div class="item blue"></div>
                <div class="item orange"></div>
                <div class="item blue"></div>
                <div class="item orange"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="main-header"></div>
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="item grey"></div>
                <div class="item purple"></div>
                <div class="item grey"></div>
                <div class="item purple"></div>
                <div class="item grey"></div>
                <div class="item purple"></div>
                <div class="item grey"></div>
                <div class="item purple"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: solid 3px black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #333;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 75px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    border: solid 1px grey;
}

.main {
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 75px;
}

.main-container {
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main-content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.main-header {
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.detail-container {
    float: right;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px grey;
}

.top-info {
    padding: 75px 0;
}

.items-container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.item {
    padding: 100px 0;
} 

.blue { background-color: blue; }
.orange { background-color: orange; }
.grey { background-color: grey; }
.purple { background-color: purple; }

.content {
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a fixed height for the container and overflow set to hidden. Since the divs exceed that height, the overflow can't be seen.

Try this:

```css
.container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: solid 3px black;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.header {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #333;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 75px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    border: solid 1px grey;
}

.main {
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 75px;
}

.main-container {
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main-content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.main-header {
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.detail-container {
    float: right;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px grey;
}

.top-info {
    padding: 75px 0;
}

.items-container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.item {
    padding: 100px 0;
} 

.blue { background-color: blue; }
.orange { background-color: orange; }
.grey { background-color: grey; }
.purple { background-color: purple; }

.content {
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="detail-container">
            <div class="top-info"></div>
            <div class="items-container">
                <div class="item blue"></div>
                <div class="item orange"></div>
                <div class="item blue"></div>
                <div class="item orange"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="main-header"></div>
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="item grey"></div>
                <div class="item purple"></div>
                <div class="item grey"></div>
                <div class="item purple"></div>
                <div class="item grey"></div>
                <div class="item purple"></div>
                <div class="item grey"></div>
                <div class="item purple"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixes my issue, but now the browser window (thick box) scrolls as well.

Comment: I'd like the entire browser window to not scroll similar to jsfiddle or other single page apps.

Comment: The thick box is the container and since it has a fixed height of 500px, if you don't want it to scroll, the divs inside must fit inside 500px or they won't be visible entirely

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this with some javascript. This should addapt to any content size of your other blocks as long as the markup structure doesn't change.

Good luck!

```
$(function(){
//creating vars based on jquery objects
$itemsContainer = $('.items-container');
$mainContent = $('.main-content');

$container = $('.container');
$header = $('.header');
$mainHeader = $('.main-header');    

//calculating heights
var containerH = $container.height();    
var headerH = $header.height();    
var mainHeaderH = $mainHeader.height();

//assigning new height to main-content class
$mainContent.css("height", (containerH - headerH - mainHeaderH) + "px");

//similar operation for items-container
//creating vars based on jquery objects
$topInfo = $('.top-info');

//calculating heights
var topInforH = $topInfo.outerHeight(); //since in your example top-info has no content only padding, you will need to use the method outerHeight instead of height

//assigning new height to main-content class
$itemsContainer.css("height", (containerH - headerH - topInforH) + "px"); });
```

By the way, I updated your jsfiddle with my solution, so you can test it.

Comment: This is awesome!!! I'm just wondering if it's cleaner to use this or redo my html/css to not rely on js.

Comment: Like one of the other guys said, the main problem is that you can't use 100% height if your element has siblings in your case on top of the element you really want to make 100%. So the solution there is to find what the right "height" for your container will be. That is what the JS does for you automatically as I figured the content will be dynamic. You can certainly refactor your html/css, but keep in mind the "100%" issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a height of 100% it sets it to the full height regardless of other sibling elements. So they are at 100% of the parent element but then the headers are pushing them down. You will have to use fixed heights on all elements. Or set one to 20% and other to 80% etc.

```
.main-content { width: 452px; }
.items-container {width: 352px; }
```